# how to make mailto: code work in custom submission for template?

Tags: html, mailto

So i was given a custom submission form HTML and CSS code template as shown below

I want to add the HTML mailto: script, so that anytime a employee enters a ticket, it will send to our help desk ticket email. My issue is i am completely lost on where to put it in the code itself so that when they click the submit now icon, it will send to the given address.

```
<!-- Main -->
            <section id="main" class="container 75%">
                <header>
                    <h2>Help Desk Ticket</h2>
                    <p>Submit a Help Desk Ticket to IT</p>
                </header>
                <div class="box">
                    <form method="post" action="#">
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="12u">
                                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="" placeholder="Subject" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="12u">
                                <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Description of Problem" rows="6"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row uniform">
                            <div class="12u">
                                <ul class="actions align-center">
                                    <li></a><input type="submit" value="Submit Ticket" /></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
```

All i want is for them to be able to click "submit ticket" and it will send to our company IT help desk email.

Comment: just modify the action of your form: `<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">`

Comment: Im very new to coding, would i put the form action at the end of the "<li></a><input type="submit" value="Submit Ticket" /></li>" or before?

Comment: you have to replace the <form> tag in your code with this one (edit the email address to send the info to)

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME!

Comment: thank you. Then consider marking the answer as accepted please

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<form method="post" action="#">
```

to this

```
<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

editing the email address with the recipient you want to send the mail to

Comment: is there a way to convert this template to a php? so it wouldnt open up outlook or gmail in the process?

Comment: Yes sure. It is possible but it is not as easy as it may seem. You need to enable php, configure it to send mail and design the script